# Sub menu wordpress toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to toggle menu items that only  have sub menu but what's happening right now is  I'm not able to find a way to toggle a single menu item, whenever I toggle every parent menu item that has children or sub menu is open toggled but not single parent item to be more clear here is the link what is i's trying to achieve

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.sidebar_menu ul ul').hide();
    if(jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').length >0)
    {
     jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').click(
      function(event) {
       jQuery(this).addClass('toggled')
       if(jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').hasClass('toggled'))
       {
       jQuery('.sidebar_menu ul ul').toggle();
       }
    
      return false;

     });
         }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar_menu">
<div class="menu-sidebar-container"><ul id="menu-sidebar" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-35 toggled"><a href="http://technocia.com/why-choose-us/">Why Choose Us?</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
 <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38"><a href="http://technocia.com/why-choose-us/">Why Choose Us?</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-36"><a href="http://technocia.com/terms-and-condition/">Terms and Condition</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
 <li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-39"><a href="http://technocia.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="http://technocia.com/resume/">Resume</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41"><a href="http://technocia.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/t36wogqr/)

your need to change the this

```
 jQuery('.sidebar_menu ul ul').toggle(); // you are toggeling every class who has .sidebar_menu
```

this

```
 jQuery(this).children('ul').toggle(); // you are only selecting its children which is ul
```

Comment: was that so simple, I was trying to achieve from last night :) btw thank you

Comment: your welcome was happy to help an do accept the and :D